# Difference between a given percent and the total

Tags: terminology

I'm writing some documentation for software and instead of writing "the difference between a given percentage and the total" I'm wondering if there is a single word term for this concept. I cannot think of one. My tentative variable name for this is "inverse_of_percent", though I know this is mathematically inaccurate, and I though I enjoy using concise terms, I am inclined to use accurate terms as well.

For clarity, the term I'm looking for would essentially define "x" here:

`45% + x = 100%`

"Variable" is not a usable option as it has a different meaning in the jargon.
I am not a mathematician, so please forgive my ignorance.

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Comment: If there were an official mathematical word it would be so obscure that using it would not help your readers. So use as many everyday words as you need to describe the number in terms they will understand.

Comment: I considered this as well, and it is a sensible option. After failing to find a fitting term on my own, I figured it would still be a question worth asking, at least for someone else that might be able to make use of the answer if it didn't end up helping my own purpose.

Comment: First Rule in the help center: "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems." Please explain in detail how this question about a mathematical concept does not belong here.

Comment: I suppose I could have posted my comment as an answer, and not voted to close. My feeling about the substance of the question hasn't changed. Since there is no standard usage, just explain what you mean ("$100\%$ minus something") rather than look for or define a new word. For a variable name I'd use "complementary_percentage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better word than inverse in this situation would be complementary. With respect to probability, if we have an event A with 45% chance of occurrence, the complement of event A (basically any other possible occurrence that is not A) will have 100 - 45% = 55% chance.

Although it's usually used in reference to events, it's better suited than inverse to refer to the percentage above.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even consider that. It made me immediately think of the color spectrum and complementary colors, so that makes a lot of sense. I was either not aware of or didn't remember being taught this term regarding this occurrence. Just curious, would this term be more commonly applied to statistics or is it readily applied across most or any mathematics discipline?